Unable to load asset with package structure
My project uses a package structure using melos. I have a package ui_components which includes ui kit and assets. Assets contains folders with images for different features: game, icons, portfolio, etc.
I also have the package game. It takes images from ui_components/assets/game. But some images are not loaded:
Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: "assets/game/idv_short.webp".

Dir ui_components/assets/game is new. If I move the images from games to other pre-existing folders, such as portfolio, then the images load fine.
In the ui_components package in pubspec.yaml I specified:
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    ...
    - assets/game/

In the game package I imported:
ui_components: 0.0.1

In packages/ui_components/lib/generated/assets.gen.dart all fine:
  /// File path: assets/game/idv_short.webp
  AssetGenImage get idvShort => 
      const AssetGenImage('assets/game/idv_short.webp');

How I use it:
BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage(Assets.weeksGame.idvShort.path),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
     ),
 ),

What am I missing?

Try adding your assets this way:
pubspec.yaml
  assets:
    - assets/images/ic_app_logo.png
    - assets/images/ic_app_logo_new.png
    - assets/images/ic_attachment.png
    - assets/images/ic_close.png

widget.dart
                       Container(
                      child: const Image(
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          image:
                              AssetImage('assets/images/ic_app_logo.png')),
                    ),

and To load an image from a package(ui_components) dependency, the package argument must be provided to AssetImage.
 const AssetImage('assets/game/ic_app_logo.png', package: 'ui_components');


package parameter in AssetImage works! Thank you very much!
